# SMD part identification

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Can someone help me to identify these two similar SMD components? My guess it could be SMD fuses, 0805 package. But I'm not a hundred percent sure.[image]

Comment: They look a bit like LEDs to me but without a bit of context I've no idea if that makes sense.

Comment: Looks like the "PTC" type of self-resetting fuse to me. Wouldn't be very high current given how thin those traces are.

Comment: What does that PCB do in the circuit? Is that perhaps protection for an USB connector?

Answer (score 0):

they are pptcs, to confirm measure the resistance at ambient temperature then heat them a bit with the hot air gun and measure again, they should have the resistance increased by quite a bit